Time component of four-velocity
While reading through Spacetime and Geometry by Sean Carroll, I came across the following passage:

"Don't get tricked into thinking that the timelike component of the four velocity of a particle at rest will always equal unity: we need to satisfy the normalisation condition, $g_{\mu\nu}U^{\mu}U^{\nu}=-1$ which in the rest frame ($U^{i}=0$) implies $U^0=\sqrt{-g_{00}}$."

However, shouldn't $U^0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g_{00}}}$? Since $g_{\mu\nu}U^{\mu}U^{\nu}=-1$, and since spatial components are zero, this would translate to $g_{00}(U^{0})^2=-1$, and thus $U^0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g_{00}}}$? I couldn't find anything about this in Sean Carroll's Errata as well, could someone explain this?

Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead.

Yes, you are correct and your explanation is correct as well. That is probably a typo.
